# New Content area Magento Shopping Cart

Tags: php, magento, cart

I need to add a new content area, just for a few lines of comments on the Magento cart page.

Underneath the products that are in the cart.

Anyone done this task before?

Hope someone can help.

Thanks

Comment: Please give more details highlighting functionality of the content area, where the content will be pushed etc.

Answer (score 1):

here are 2 links which will sure help you to add a comment box in cart page

[Free module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/brainvire-order-comment-order-comment-magento-extension.html)

just check above free module with detail description with detail sure it will defiantly help you.

or check with [manual code](http://magebase.com/magento-extensions/free-magento-extension-customer-comments-in-the-checkout/)

*i am not associate with above link it is just for knowledge share and help you to solve ur issue*

hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks everyone, will try these now!

Answer (score 1):

IF you are working on single application and if you don't need to override magento core modules then you may change cart file.

app/design/frontend/`<package>/<theme>`/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

This file includes cart items for e.g you want to display message underneath of product name, you may find below code in above file, that will print your message.

```
<h2 class="product-name">
        <?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?></a>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
 <!-- ADD YOUR CUSTOM CONTENT HERE -->
</h2>
```

Hope this will help for you!

Cheers!